# Angular, Get Index Of Dynamically Created Component Inside ViewContainerRef

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the **index** of a dynamically created component inside **ViewContainerRef**

I need to get the **index** so I can **destroy** the component if I wanted too.

Code Below

```
@ViewChild('dynamicInsert', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicInsert: ViewContainerRef

componentFactory

constructor(
  private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(AssetOptionComponent);
}

addAssetOption() {
  const dynamicComponent = <AssetOptionComponent>this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(this.componentFactory).instance
  // how to get index of this dynamically generated component ^^^^
}
```

Trying to use

`this.dynamicInsert.remove(index: number)` to destroy component

but I first need the **index** of the dynamically created component

`this.dynamicInsert.indexOf(viewRef: viewRef)`

Answer (score 6):

To get the index you can use [indexOf](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef#indexOf) method and [hostView](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#hostView) property:

```
const index = this.dynamicInsert.indexOf(dynamicComponent.hostView)
```

Also note that if you don't specify the index view container will destroy the last component:

```
  remove(index?: number): void {
    const viewData = detachEmbeddedView(this._data, index);
    if (viewData) {
      Services.destroyView(viewData);
    }
  }

   export function detachEmbeddedView(elementData: ElementData, viewIndex?: number): ViewData|null {
  const embeddedViews = elementData.viewContainer !._embeddedViews;
     if (viewIndex == null || viewIndex >= embeddedViews.length) {
        viewIndex = embeddedViews.length - 1;
     }
```

So if you have only one component you don't need to pass index.

To remove all components you can use `clear` method.

Comment: Yep! You can also just store a ref to the component, and a separate ref for the instance. -->  ref = this.container.createComponent(component)   --> instance = ref.instance --> Then you can just use  ref.destroy()

Comment: This method does not work for `const dynamicComponent = <AssetOptionComponent>this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(this.componentFactory).instance` but works for `const dynamicComponent = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(this.componentFactory)`. Gives an error of `Property 'hostView' does not exist on type 'AssetOptionComponent'`

Comment: Yeah hostView is a property of the underlying ComponentRef<T> object, not of an instance.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get the index of the instance

Comment: @locnguyen, view container stores component refs, not instances, that is why it returns component ref. A component instance is just part of component ref. The way I showed is the only correct way

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to destroy the created component you may consider a shortcut by just subscribing to it's observable destroy:

```
addAssetOption() {
   const dynamicComponent: ComponentRef<any> = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent(this.componentFactory);
     dynamicComponent.instance.destroy.subscribe(() => dynamicComponent.destroy())
}
```

and then upon removing event, in AssetOptionComponent, call it:

```
 export class AssetOptionComponent  {
  destroy = new Destroyable();
  delete(){
    this.destroy.delete();
  }
}

export class Destroyable extends Subject<any>{
 delete() {
    this.next();
  } 
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lnawap?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts)

Comment: Please see the StackBlitz demo in the updated answer